# Why modal data is not posted to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to post data from modal in bootstrap to controller in codeigniter. But the data is not posted.

```
public function save()
{
     if (!empty($_POST['UserName'])){

         $data = $this->input->post('UserName');
         echo $data;
     }
     else
     {
         echo "Not posted";
     }
}
```

In the view,

```
 <div class="modal-body"> 

    <?php echo form_open('Supplier/save'); ?>

    <table>
        <tr>    
                <td>User Name
                <input id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" class="validate" required></td>
        </tr>       
    </table>

    <?php echo form_close(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: How are you submitting the form?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need?

```
echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Submit Post!');
```

Also consider using isset() instead of !empty(). For example when you check number value empty() for number 0 will return true.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to use a submit as said @Mateusz Petkiewicz.
then why you don`t use the CI input post and form_validator like

```
public function save(){

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('UserName', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

    if( $this->form_validation->run()){
        echo $data;
    }
    else{
        echo validation_errors();
        echo "<hr>Not posted";
    }
}
```